# What is meant by "one-quarter to half of the average income"?

Tags: meaning

> For more than 21,000 adults, the sound means one thing: 2,250 Kenyan
>   shillings appearing in their bank accounts. The cash equals
>   **one-quarter to half of the average income** for a two-adult household in
>   Bomet County, one of the poorest in Kenya.

What is meant by "one-quarter to half of the average income"?

Comment: What **do you** think it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use 'to' to link the lower and upper limits of a range of numbers or quantities. The cash is between 0.25 (one quarter) and 0.5 (half, or one half) of the average income (etc). You can replace 'equals' with 'is between'. Eggs cost 50p to 65p per dozen; the water in the lake is 20 to 30 metres deep.